# how can I make my json array sort function case insensitive?

Tags: jquery

I have the following fiddle that is my attempt at

- taking a json array
- sort the array by the displayname value
- add the sorted array to the DOM as list items

My issue is that I want to be able to make the sort NOT take into consideration the case of the value when sorting... Im noticing that it considers the case and puts uppercase values FIRST.

Im fairly certain its a matter of integrating .toLowerCase() somewhere but all my attempts have failed.  Where / how do I apply .toLowerCase() to make the sort case insensitive?

[js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/pggM3/11/)

```
function sortResults(prop, asc) {
    //SORT THE ARRAY BY THE PASSED NODE VALUE...
          myArray.jsonData = myArray.jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (asc) return (a[prop]> b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
                else return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
          });

     showInDOM();   
 }
```

Comment: are all properties strings?

Comment: @MauricePerry  Yes, all are strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function toLowerCase() and convert to string with `+ ""`

```
myArray.jsonData.sort(function(a, b) {
   var comp = ((a[prop]+"").toLowerCase() >
               (b[prop]+"").toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1 ;
   return asc ? comp : -comp;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are always sorting strings, you can use:

```
function(a,b){
   return a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase();
}
```

which in your example would be:

```
myArray.jsonData.sort(function(a,b){
    var result, 
        av=a[prop].toLowerCase(), 
        bv=b[prop].toLowerCase();
    return asc ? av > bv : av < bv;
}
```

Comment: Note that this does no error checking, such as assuring both elements contain a 'prop' value.